# how do I print queryset dictonary in django template

Tags: python, django, templates, view

How do I print the below for loop (last for loop) which is printing all prods in my template?  I tried to find answers but I'm nowhere close to finding one. Please help me solve this issue.

```
allProds = []
catalogs = Catalog.objects.all().distinct().order_by('name')
categories = Category.objects.all().distinct().order_by('name')
for catalog in catalogs:
    allProds.append(catalog)
    for category in categories.filter(catalog_name=catalog.id):
        allProds.append(category)
        products = Product.objects.values('name','image')
                   .filter(category_name=category)
        allProds.append(products)
for p in range(len(allProds)):
    print(allProds[p])
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial03/

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
allProds.append(products)
```

with

```
for prod in products:
    allProds.append(prod)
```

And at the end:

```
for prod in allProds:
    print(prod)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I did try that and it prints 

Catalog Name: Electronics 
Category Name: Television
Products:
{'name': 'Samsung', 'image': 'shop/images/SmartTV.JPG', 'price': '100'}

but my question is how do I print that in my template product.html?  

In my product.html, When I use {% for a, b, c in allProds %}
        {{a}}
    {% endfor %} 

I get the following error :

Need 3 values to unpack in for loop; got 1.

Comment: Thank you Horatiu, I'm able to figure out. Your answer helped me a lot.